# Alinear texto verticalmente y proporcionalmente al lado de una imagen CSS

Tags: css, imagen

Muy buenas, estoy practicando con CSS con un diseño de una galeria de fotos, sin embargo me encuentro con el inconveniente d que me toca alinear el nombre de los trabajos al lado derecho de la imagen d forma vertical como se ve en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tecnicamente ya lo hice usando transform y translate pero me toca ir cambiando porcentajes en cada media query y es bastante engorroso. Me prguntaba si habia alguna manera de hacerlo donde se fuera calculando por el viewport o simplemente estuviera fijado alli. En esta version desktop el texto se alinea correctamente pero cuando paso a version movil ya se cuando comienzan los problemas xD, por so quiero saber si alguna manera de que se vaya ajustando automaticamente. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

```
  <body>
<main>
  <section class="crew">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="crew-gallery">
        <div class="crew-gallery__img">
          <img src="img/photo1.png" alt="photo" />
          <h3 class="crew-gallery__title">Bill Mahoney</h3>
          <p class="crew-gallery__job">Product owner</p>
        </div>
        <div class="crew-gallery__img">
          <img src="img/photo2.png" alt="photo" />
          <h3 class="crew-gallery__title">Bill Mahoney</h3>
          <p class="crew-gallery__job">Product owner</p>
        </div>
        <div class="crew-gallery__img">
          <img src="img/photo3.png" alt="photo" />
          <h3 class="crew-gallery__title">Bill Mahoney</h3>
          <p class="crew-gallery__job">Product owner</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

**ESTILOS**

```
      *,
  *::before,
  *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  html {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  }
  .container {
    max-width: 1440px;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 50px 12px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 264px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .crew-gallery {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
  .crew-gallery__job {
    /* TEXTO LADO DERECHO  */
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-34rem, -21rem);
  }


  .crew-gallery__img:nth-child(even) {
    margin-top: 90px;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .crew-gallery {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado un usuario que estaba haciendo ese diseño y la solucion simplemente era hacer que el contenedor fuera relativo y darle un width mayor que el de la imagen. El texto se pone en absolute, right : 0 y listo.

**Codigo**

```
img {
    width: 180px;
  }

  /* Contenedor  */
  .crew-gallery__img {
    width: 200px;
  }

  
  /* texto  */
  .crew-gallery__job {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "PT Serif", serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.625rem;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    font-family: "PT Serif", serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  }
```

Dejo link del proyecto ya terminado por si a alguien le sirve
https://serene-jepsen-c0a490.netlify.app/